# WordPress is creating a lot of draft posts

Tags: posts, draft

My WordPress install (with the following plugins) randomly creates Draft posts whenever I load the posts page. Is there a way to find out which plugin is doing this (aside from deactivating)? Has anyone had this problem?

`Admin Tree View
Advanced Custom Fields
ACF: Flexible Content Field
ACF: Repeater Field
Breadcrumb NavXT
Disqus
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP
Google Analytics for WordPress
Gravity Forms
Gravity Forms Campaign Monitor Add-On
iframe
IPU-Chart
Simple Sitemap
sxss Admin Notes
TablePress
W3 Total Cache
WordPress SEO
WP-Mail-SMTP`

Comment: Which posts page?

Comment: Just in the backend. When you go to the Posts section. I had about 1000+ drafts that were created. I can't tell what plugin created them or why they were created.

Comment: I have the same problem recently. Did you solve it?

Comment: I had the same problem And I solved it
You can refer here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatic-creation-of-post-drafts/

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start with an issue like this is using debug mode in WP.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

If you know exactly which action triggers the creation of a draft post, then it is repeatable and you have a basis for a solution.  Based on your question, "whenever I load the posts page" is what creates your unwanted drafts.  Not sure exactly what you mean by that as it could be interpreted to mean a few different things.

Deactivate all plugins - test if a draft is created when you "load the posts page".  If no draft is created, it is a plugin issue.

Reactivate plugins one at a time and retest each time until you locate the problem.

If deactivating plugins does not stop the auto-draft behavior, the problem is likely theme related.  Switching themes will isolate that issue separately.

Answer (score 0):

in your database look into wp_postmeta table to see the latest entries.

Comment: This does **not** answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a multisite installation. It turned out that the wp_posts table was missing the Auto Increment setting on the post_id column.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.